# Organising right side elements in header

Tags: html, css

I wrote a code for header as follows:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 992px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
#header {
  /*background-color: #166bb3;
    height: 85px;
    min-width: 992px;
    width: 1024px;*/
  /* padding: 0 6%;*/
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  background-color: #166bb3;
}
#logo {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
#headerdetails {
  padding: 25px 0px;
  min-width: 400px;
}
.hddtlsItems {
  color: #ffbf00;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
.subhddtlsItems {
  color: #FFF;
  /*margin-right: 3%;*/
  font-size: 9px;
  /* padding: 0px;*/
  float: right;
  min-width: 61px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="header" role="banner">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <div id="headerdetails" class="pull-right col-md-5"> <span class="col-md-3 hddtlsItems pull-right"><img src="images/routes.png" alt="r" style="width: inherit;">14567
                    <span class="subhddtlsItems">Routes</span>
      </span> <span class="col-md-3 hddtlsItems pull-right"><img src="images/transaction.png" alt="t" style="width: inherit;">$345.45
                    <span class="subhddtlsItems">Transaction values</span>
      </span> <span class="col-md-3 hddtlsItems pull-right"><img src="images/conversation.png" alt="c" style="width: inherit;">18456
                    <span class="subhddtlsItems">Conversations</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But right side elements aren't same as shown in this picture:
[image: img]
How can I move subtitles more upwards as shown in picture? Other elements like `18456`, `$345` etc are proper. For best results, execute the above code and view it in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to you layout, you can just add

```
position: relative;
top: -8px;
```

(or whatever pixel value) to .subhddtlsItems but it's not the cleanest way to achieve this. Unfortunately I would have to change all your layout to make something more maintainable and consistent.

Comment: Well... how would you change my layout? What would you do?

Comment: You put spans within spans (it's valid but not the right way for what you try to achieve. you should separates the 'labels' and the 'values' (14203 and routes for example). Your right container should be the only right floating element. Elements inside should float to left so you don't need to revert all your markup (styling should adapt to content and you should never adapt content to style). The way you did it works so that's ok, but you may have some difficulties if you need to change anything in the future.